# SQL return rows in a "round-robin" order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bunch of URLs stored in a table waiting to be scraped by a script. However, many of those URLs are from the same site. I would like to return those URLs in a "site-friendly" order (that is, try to avoid two URLs from the same site in a row) so I won't be accidentally blocked by making too many http requests in a short time.

The database layout is something like this:

```
create table urls (
    site varchar,       -- holds e.g. www.example.com or stockoverflow.com
    url varchar unique
);
```

Example result:

```
SELECT url FROM urls ORDER BY mysterious_round_robin_function(site);

http://www.example.com/some/file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
http://use.perl.org/
http://www.example.com/some/other/file
http://stackoverflow.com/tags
```

I thought of something like "`ORDER BY site <> @last_site DESC`" but I have no idea how to go about writing something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this article in my blog for more detailed explanations on how it works:

- [**PostgreSQL: round-robin order**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/21/postgresql-round-robin-records/)

With new `PostgreSQL 8.4`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  site, url, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY site ORDER BY url) AS rn
        FROM    urls
        )
ORDER BY
        rn, site
```

With elder versions:

```
SELECT  site,
        (
        SELECT  url
        FROM    urls ui
        WHERE   ui.site = sites.site
        ORDER BY
                url
        OFFSET  total
        LIMIT   1
        ) AS url
FROM    ( 
        SELECT  site, generate_series(0, cnt - 1) AS total
        FROM    (
                SELECT  site, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM    urls
                GROUP BY
                        site
                ) s
        ) sites
ORDER BY
        total, site
```

, though it can be less efficient.

Comment: The last query *really* needs to be checked for efficiency if your table is large.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! Looks like voodoo to me, but I'll figure it out someday.

Comment: I'm still using 8.3, but the table is only ~150 rows so far.

Comment: @hhaamu: note that the query time for the last query will grow exponentially. I'd test ot on the maximum number of records you are planning to achieve.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Will do. Very much doubt there will be 1000 rows. And the query won't be run all that often (once a day or more seldom).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overcomplicating this.  Why not just use

ORDER BY NewID()

Comment: Nice! Beautifully simplistic.

Comment: Is that similar to RANDOM()? If it is, it's not quite good enough. There are a couple of sites that comprise 10-30% of the table.

Comment: @hhaamu: I think that you're underestimating the power of RANDOM :

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for round-robin, but I think a simple

```
SELECT site, url FROM urls ORDER BY RANDOM()
```

will do the trick. It should work even if urls from the same site are clustered in db.

Answer (score 0):

If the URLs don't change very often, you can come up with a somewhat-complicated job that you could run periodically (nightly?) which would assign integers to each record based on the different sites present.

What you can do is write a routine that parses the domain out from a URL (you should be able to find a snippet that does this nearly anywhere).

Then, you create a temporary table that contains each unique domain, plus a number.

Then, for every record in your URLs table, you look up the domain in your temp table, assign that record the number stored there, and add a large number to that temp table's number.

Then for the rest of the day, sort by the number.

---

Here's an example with the five records you used in your question:

URLs:

- http://www.example.com/some/file
- http://www.example.com/some/other/file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags
- http://use.perl.org/

Temp table:

```
example.com       1
stackoverflow.com 2
perl.org          3
```

Then for each URL, you look up the value in the temp table, and add 3 to it (because it's got 3 distinct records):

### Iteration 1:

URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/some/file         1
http://www.example.com/some/other/file   NULL
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask   NULL
https://stackoverflow.com/tags            NULL
http://use.perl.org/                     NULL
```

Temp table:

```
example.com       4
stackoverflow.com 2
perl.org          3
```

### Iteration 2:

URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/some/file         1
http://www.example.com/some/other/file   4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask   NULL
https://stackoverflow.com/tags            NULL
http://use.perl.org/                     NULL
```

Temp table:

```
example.com       7
stackoverflow.com 2
perl.org          3
```

et cetera until you get to

```
http://www.example.com/some/file         1
http://www.example.com/some/other/file   4
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask   2
https://stackoverflow.com/tags            5
http://use.perl.org/                     3
```

For a lot of records, it's going to be slow. And it will be difficult to work with many inserts/deletions, but the result will be a flawless round-robin ordering.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler and faster solution...

- add a sort_order column of type TEXT
- add an ON INSERT trigger which sets sort_order to md5( url )
- index on sort_order
- grab the rows in (sort_order, primary key) order

-> it's very fast and indexed
-> rows will come in a repeatable, yet random order